# How was the normal form of this extensive game calculated?

Tags: game-theory, bayesian, nash-equilibrium

[image]

An explanation for just one set of payoffs will be fine (e.g. CH,CH). Because of the overlapping information sets, I am confused as to how the payoffs are calculated. For the CH,CH pair, I don't know how they got 3w/8 - 1L/4....

source: http://faculty.haas.berkeley.edu/stadelis/Game%20Theory/econ160_week7b.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The strategy profile $(CH,CH)$ indicates that both players choose $C$ at their first information set and $H$ at their second information set, as indicated in the graph below. So player 1's payoff from this profile is
\begin{equation}
\frac14(0)+\frac14(0)+\frac14(w)+\frac14\left(\frac{w}2-L\right)=\frac38w-\frac14L
\end{equation}

[image]